# Oracle 12C：Return the record after insert values

Tags: c#, oracle

I want to get the value to insert a table in C#,something like this:

```
begin
insert into bk_library(floor,section) values('foo2','bar') 
returning id into :outid;
select *from bk_library where id=:outid;
end;
```

Unfortunately, I failed

> error info: Kiss.Linq.Linq2Sql.Test.EntryPoint.TestInsertReturnId:
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-06550: line 3, column
>   1: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

---

> ```
>     [Test]
>     public void TestInsertReturnId()
>     {
>         int ret = 0;
>         string connstring = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=pdborcl)));User Id=system;Password=****;";
>
>         string sql = @"insert into bk_library(floor,section) values('foo','bar') returning id into :outid";
>          sql = getSqlString();
>         using (DbConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring))
>         {
>             conn.Open();
>             DbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
>             command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
>             command.CommandText = sql;
>
>             OracleParameter lastId = new OracleParameter(":outid", OracleDbType.Int32);
>             lastId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
>             command.Parameters.Add(lastId);
>             ret = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
>
>                // this code work fine ,now I want to get the entire record
>             LogManager.GetLogger<EntryPoint>().Info("The new id ={0}", lastId.Value.ToString()); 
>
>             conn.Close();
>         }
>         Assert.AreNotEqual(ret, 0);
>     }
> ```

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do? You just created the "row" in the database and you have the data already, why fetch it again? Maybe have a look at Entity Framework or LinqToSql?

Comment: In this case the primary column of the table is identity(http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1.php),when insert a value I do not know the id,now I want to get the entire record.

Comment: Yes, but you are getting the id back from the query, why do you need the entire record? And since you are not using any modeling framework?

Answer (score 0):

`ParameterDirection` should be `ReturnValue`

```
lastId.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Comment: My mistake，this code" LogManager.GetLogger<EntryPoint>().Info("The new id ={0}", lastId.Value.ToString()); " work fine,I can get the id,now I want to get the entire record not only the ID.

Answer (score 0):

From < http://arjudba.blogspot.ch/2008/07/pls-00428-into-clause-is-expected-in.html?m=1>

You need to write `SELECT * INTO some_variable FROM bk_library` instead of `SELECT * FROM bk_library` because I assume you want to store the data retrieved somehow. Therefore you need to declare a new variable `some_variable` (I assume of type string) and modify your SELECT statement as above. The data from the statement will then be stored in your new variable.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks,You inspired me,I change my sql like this:

declare idnum integer;
begin
insert into bk_library(floor,section) values('foo2','bar') 

returning id into :outid;
select id into idnum from bk_library where id=:outid;
end;

Now I want to get the all columns value,how can I do that?

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-may/o32plsql-1578019.html

Comment: Thanks,now I have this sql:declare bk_library_shadow bk_library%ROWTYPE;
begin
insert into bk_library(floor,section) values('foo2','bar') returning id into :outid;
select * into bk_library_shadow from bk_library where id=:outid;
end;